# how to solve no such column: todo_todo.title

Tags: python, django, database, migrate

I'm making a basic todo app in Django3.
how to solve no such column: todo_todo.title error??
I can't solve this problem.
here is my todo models and views.

this is my todo/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone 


class Todo(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200) 
    details=models.TextField() 
    date=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now) 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect 
from django.contrib import messages 

from .forms import TodoForm 
from .models import Todo 

############################################### 

def index(request): 
    item_list = Todo.objects.order_by("-date") 
    if request.method == "POST": 
        form = TodoForm(request.POST) 
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save() 
            return redirect('todo') 
    form = TodoForm() 

    page = { 
             "forms" : form, 
             "list" : item_list, 
             "title" : "TODO LIST", 
           } 
    return render(request, 'todo/index.html', page) 

### function to remove item, it recive todo item id from url ## 
def remove(request, item_id): 
    item = Todo.objects.get(id=item_id) 
    item.delete() 
    messages.info(request, "item removed !!!") 
    return redirect('todo')
```

Comment: Can you put your error traceback here ?

Comment: can you also show your template please

Comment: Did you create and apply the migrations?

Comment: @KlausD. yes migrations are success

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you run

```
python manage.py makemigrations

# and 
python manage.py migrate
```

The error looks like a database error.

Also, Change

```
item_list = Todo.objects.order_by("-date")
```

To

```
item_list = Todo.objects.all().order_by("-date")
```

An error may probably come from your template view `todo\index.html` where you will be trying to to access `todo.title` but it is not being passed correctly from the view.
The `.all()` function returns the queryset of objects you need from your database for the Todo model

Comment: You may want to update your question by adding your error log so we see exactly what the problem is.